# javascript function not defined error

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine SDK for Python. When I write Javascript functions in a separate .js file and include it in the .py file, I get the following errors in Chrome:-

**In .py file**:-
Uncaught reference error: initFunc is not defined.

**In .js file**:-
Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token <
Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html.

**Source codes**:-
**.py file**

```
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print ''
print '\
<head>\
    <title>Page</title>\
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">\
    </script>\
</head>\
<body>\
<input type="button" onclick="initFunc();" value="Test" />\
</body>\
'
```

**.js file**

    `function initFunc(){alert("hi");}\`

All the errors disappear when I include the initFunc in the .py file itself.

Comment: Your print syntax is wrong; you need triple quotes or a `\ ` on the first line of your multi-line string. You also have an unquoted `<br>` in python code, unless that's an attempt to format your code for SO and not actually in your code.  You almost certainly want to use a WSGI framework and template system rather than `print`ing HTTP headers and raw HTML, anyway.

Comment: I had \ in my code. <br> is not a part of my code. Messed it up while trying to format the code here. Corrected these two typos in the code above.

Comment: Can you please help me debugging the code as written above now. :)

Comment: what does app.yaml look like? Are you actually serving the .js file in response to a request for it, or are you seeing a 404 in your logs?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have both  `main.py` and `foo.js` in the same root directory.
You should map a route for the static contents of your project like javascripts in the `app.yaml` config file:

1.Create a directory called `static/javascripts` in the Root of your project

2.Add the javascripts static section in your `app.yaml` handlers

```
 -url: /javascripts  
    static_dir: app/static/javascripts
```

3.Modify your code like this:

```
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print ''
print """
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/script.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="initFunc();" value="Test" />
</body>
"""
```

As Wooble correctly suggested, you should avoid to code with `print` and switch to a more fancy [Python web-frameworks](http://www.gaecupboard.com/tag/web-frameworks/python?category=Libraries) supported by GAE.